# Debian, doesn't work the option “Open in the terminal”

Tags: debian, terminal, nautilus, right-click

Opening nautilus and using the usual right-click and then clicking on "open the terminal" nothing happens. This has happened after (I think) the daily update of Debian or the installation of Terminator sofware. I searched on the net but I didn't found anything ... what's the problem? I have Debian version 7.8 (wheezy) 64 bits. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem on a couple debian boxes, so its not terminator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Terminator in my case, I tried to remove it and the option started to work again. * palmface *